# Xcode Archive made an empty Products folder : Validate Content Button is grayed

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods

I'm trying to build an archive file for my first IOS app uploading with Xcode.
But after archiving, the Validate Content button is grayed.
Like this:

[image: My archive file is grouped as Generic Xcode Archive]

I think that's because the Products folder, which XCode made in the app archive package( .xcarchive file ), is empty.

[image: My Products folder is empty]

```
My Xcode is ver. 11.4.1
And CocoaPods is ver 1.9.1
```

As an experiment, I made a new project and that archiving went well.
So Maybe something wrong with my main app.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Now I figured it out somehow.
I made a new project file, and copied everything to the new project, it works well.

So I still don't know why my old one didn't work.
But let me close this question.